# 2013 Workflow Manger Fresh Install

Tags: workflow-manager

I need to install the 2013 Workflow Manager on a 2019 site.
According to the documentation this needs to be done using the Microsoft Web Platform Installer which was retired last year.
I've tried installing it directly from the msi but it doesn't install properly. It is visible in Add or Remove Programs but it doesn't appear in Start Menu programs list and can't be retrieved with the search box.
I'm thinking it is no longer possible to do a fresh install?

Answer (score 0):

According to this post that was posted on the 16th of february 2023, Workflow Manager is not available through the Microsoft Web Platform Installer anymore. It's now a single installation, see the second link.

> Microsoft will continue to provide technical support for existing deployments of Service Bus and Microsoft Workflow Manager until the version of SharePoint Server they're being used with reaches end of support, or until July 14, 2026, whichever comes first.

> However, **the Service Bus and Microsoft Workflow Manager installers are
> no longer available from the Microsoft Web Platform Installer (WebPI)**.
> Customers who need new SharePoint 2013 workflow engine installations
> can only install SharePoint Workflow Manager.

[Announcing the release of SharePoint Workflow Manager for SharePoint Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/announcing-the-release-of-sharepoint-workflow-manager-for/ba-p/3744881)

[SharePoint Workflow Manager Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=104867)